# Azure VM Extensions

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I'm executing the following:

```
Set-AzureRmVMExtension `
  -VMName 'servername' `
  -ResourceGroupName 'rgname' `
  -Name 'JoinAD' `
  -ExtensionType 'JsonADDomainExtension' `
  -Publisher 'Microsoft.Compute' `
  -TypeHandlerVersion '1.0' `
  -Location 'West Europe' `
  -Settings @{'Name' = 'domain.com'; 'OUPath' = 'OU=Server 2012 R2,OU=Servers,DC=domain,DC=com'; 'User' = 'domain.com\username'; 'Restart' = 'true'; 'Options' = 3} `
  -ProtectedSettings @{'Password' = 'password'}
```

and get this error:

> Set-AzureRmVMExtension : Long running operation failed with status
>   'Failed'. StartTime: 18.04.2016 18:03:30 EndTime: 18.04.2016 18:04:50
>   OperationID: 76825458-6c50-404d-bb1a-b27c722b1760 Status: Failed
>   ErrorCode: VMExtensionProvisioningError ErrorMessage: VM has reported
>   a failure when processing extension 'JoinAD'. Error message: "Join
>   completed for Domain 'ddomain.com'". At line:1 char:1
>   + Set-AzureRmVMExtension `
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmVMExtension], ComputeCloudException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.SetAzureVMExtensionCommand

What am I missing?

Comment: This is not related to the Azure Automation service, I recommend changing the tag to azure-virtual-machine so the right folks can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Kept having trouble with extension, therefore opted to perform the domain join using PowerShell `Add-Computer` without extensions.

One possibly cause might be that NSG configurations block connectivity to the internet and with that to services running in the Azure data center.